# How to conditionally render reason-react component?

Tags: reason, reason-react

Something that has started appearing in my code quite a bit is:

```
<Parent>
  {if (condition) {
     <Child />;
   } else {
     <div />;
   }}
  <Sibling />
</Parent>;
```

Basically I only want the `Child` to render if the condition is true, otherwise render nothing.

It feels wrong putting the `div` in the else condition, since this renders a `div` that really shouldn't be there. How can I conditionally render a component without having to render an unnecessary element if the condition is false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `React.null` instead of the empty `div`.

ReasonML forces you to have the same type in the if and else blocks, and as you return a `React.element` in the if block, you also need to return one in the else block.

You can however use ternary, if you want your code to be a bit shorter:

```
<Parent>
  {condition ? <Child /> : React.null}
  <Sibling />
</Parent>;
```